# How to change status bar color in themeable browser in Android with Ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using themeable browser [plugin link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser/) for display url in my Ionic application.

Default themeable browser take black color in status bar, and I have to change it. I am trying below code for that but nothing happens.

```
    Window window = cordova.getActivity().getWindow();

    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
    {
         window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(cordova.getActivity(), android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
    }
```

I am changing this code in Android file which is located here:

https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser/blob/master/src/android/ThemeableBrowser.java

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the dialog height is incorrectly calculated just fork the plugin and correct the height calculation. The status bar will maintain the color it had before opening the ThemeableBrowser :

```
    Display display = cordova.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    lp.height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the source code as below, it worked.

```
package com.initialxy.cordova.themeablebrowser;

import android.os.Build;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.Display;
import android.graphics.Point;


public class ThemeableBrowser extends CordovaPlugin{

    public String showWebPage(final String url, final Options features) {
    
        Display display = cordova.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = size.x;
        lp.height = size.y;
        
        Window window = cordova.getActivity().getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(cordova.getActivity(), android.R.color.white));
        }
        
        dialog.setContentView(main);
        dialog.show();
```